# Reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source doesn't fix Broadcom wireless adapter 14e4:4365 rev01

Tags: wireless

I tried reinstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` but my Broadcom wireless adapter 14e4:4365 rev01 is still not working

Comment: first i removed existing dirver by
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
and then install it and after same problem exist ,so i try to install by
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
reboot
problem still exist

Comment: Have you tried the other method (`firmware-b43-installer`)? It worked for me.